# Is there any inference we can make about a function if its second derivative is constant?

Tags: derivatives

I recently learned about the concept of the 2ns derivative  test, and while solving some sums I encountered some functions which had a constant 2nd derivative. Now I made a simple inference that it means that the function has only one out of the two extremes. Is there any other inference  we can make as well, given a constant value for the 2nd derivative test?

Comment: If the second derivative is constant, can you integrate it and say something about the first? Once you've done that, can you say anything about the function itself?

Comment: Acceleration due to gravity is a constant: -9.8 m /s^2.  So the kind of curves you get are those that look like an arc made when you throw a ball in the air - parabolas.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. 
You could start by thinking about whether you know any functions with a constant second derivative.

Hint.
You know (or should) that a function with a constant first derivative is linear. Can you use that to figure out what a function with a constant second derivative must be?

Comment: Yeah, so the first derivative of the function is a straight line, right?

Comment: @divyamsureka Yes.